# Passing mathematical function as function argument

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am beginner level java programmer.

I want a function which takes a mathematical function (i.e. sin, cos, exp() ) as argument and integrate it.

Note that I want to pass the function, not the value of function.

The function is such that it receives a mathematical function as argument, an initial value, initial derivative and the point upto which it integrates. The function returns the area under the curve.

I don't even know if this is possible, if this is possible please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a method in Java that can do integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886145/is-there-a-method-in-java-that-can-do-integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package offers a way to store functions as references.

As long as your functions are of the same *type*, you can use them as arguments. `sin` and `cos` for example are both of the type `double -> double`, in terms of Java they are a `DoubleFunction<Double>`  or better yet `DoubleUnaryOperator` (if you want to use primitives) or `Function<Double, Double>`.

This means you can declare functions like these:

```
public void foo(DoubleUnaryOperator f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       System.out.println(f.apply((double) i));
}
```

This function takes another functions and calls it ten times, with numbers from `0 .. 9`.

You can create far more complex things with this, e.g. by also passing an appropriate supplier and much more.

Passing functions in this way is done either via [*lambda expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) or *method references*. Both are equal:

```
foo(Math::sin);
foo(d -> Math.sin(d));
```

Lets say you want to create a method that takes a function that describes a graph, an initial value, and end value, and a step size (delta), and want to calculate the area under the graph in the given bounds.

Then the function would have this signature and skeleton implementation:

```
public double area(DoubleUnaryOperator graph, double start, double end, double delta) {
    DoubleStream stream = DoubleStream
        .iterate(start, d -> d + delta)
        .limit((long)((end-start)/delta);
        // stream now consists of all values between start and end
        // with a difference of delta between them
        // now map it & collect it
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, although I am beginner and this isn't my familiar territory, I will dig into it and implement your solution.

Comment: @user85218 If this answer helped you, please consider upvoting and [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it ;)

Comment: Yeah that was absolutely helpful, and tried to upvote, but it says vote only recorded but not publicly displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using method references:

```
List<Double> list=getRandomDoubles();
list.stream().map(Math::sqrt) //Map to the square root
             .map(Math::log)//Map to the logarithm of the number
             .forEach(System.out::println);//Print each number
```

Answer (score -2):

Java is a OOP (Object Oriented Programming Language), and does not accept a *function* in a parameter.

To have such a behavior, since Java 8, they added the possibility of using `Lambda` expressions, to simulate the possibility of using function in the code, but in reality, you are always conveying object...

As you are a beginner like you said, I'd recommend some readings first:

- [Read this article here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces)
- [Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIrMbAQSU34)